# Open Razor Component as new window

Tags: .net, macos, razor, blazor

How can I open new Window with razor component?
I try open new Window with Counter() razor component getting this error.

```
@code {
    private void openNewWindow(){
        Window secondWindow = new Window(new Counter());
        Application.Current.OpenWindow(secondWindow);

    }
}
```

error **CS1503: Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'ProjectName.Pages.Counter' to 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Page'**

This is Maui Blazor App project, I want to allow users to open the charts panel to new window.

Comment: Welcome, Please insert your code as a text instead of picture, Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to open a new Tab, or is this related to .NET MAUI?

Comment: @AlirezaK updated to code.

Comment: @MarvinKlein This is related to .net Maui not web. I want open new window base on razor component.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with it for a while, and found a workaround here:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11746

This workaround adds a property to the blazor `Router` that does the page navigation.

Based on the standard MAUI Blazor template project, do the following:

**Main.razor**

Add the `StartPath` property and inject the `NavigationManager`. When the StartPath property changes, navigate to the new StartPath.

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Main).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code
{
    [Parameter] public string StartPath { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StartPath))
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo(StartPath);
        }

        base.OnParametersSet();
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

Add `x:Name` to the `BlazorWebView` component

```xml
<BlazorWebView x:Name="blazorWebView" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
    <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Main}" />
    </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
</BlazorWebView>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

Add the `StartPath` property to the `RootComponent`

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(string startPath = null)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (startPath != null)
        {
            blazorWebView.RootComponents[0].Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "StartPath", startPath },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

That's it!

You can now use the following code to open a new window, pointing to the *Counter* page.

```
var counterWindow = new Window
{
    Page = new MainPage("/counter")
};

Application.Current.OpenWindow(counterWindow);
```